# missing few lines to print

Tags: python, json, strip

below is my code:

```
output_dict = {}
for item in show_vs:
    splitted = item.split(": ")
    if len(splitted) <= 1:
        continue
    output_dict[
        splitted[0].strip()
    ] = splitted[1].strip()
jsn = json.dumps(output_dict, indent=4)
print(jsn)
```

below is my data, the code prints only last 10 keys and its values in json format but it is not printing the first 20 keys and its values at all, any suggestions?

```
show_vs = [
    'VSID:            0   ',
    'VRID:            0   ',
    'Type:            VSX Gateway',
    'Name:            chckpt-fw1a',
    'Security Policy: VS-policy',
    'Installed at:    12Jan2023 21:57:15',
    'SIC Status:      Trust',
    'Connections number: 52',
    'Connections peak: 152',
    'Connections limit:  14900',

    'VSID:            1   ',
    'VRID:            1   ',
    'Type:            VSX Gateway',
    'Name:            chckpt-fw1a',
    'Security Policy: VS-policy',
    'Installed at:    12Jan2023 21:57:15',
    'SIC Status:      Trust',
    'Connections number: 52',
    'Connections peak: 152',
    'Connections limit:  14900',

    'VSID:            2   ',
    'VRID:            2   ',
    'Type:            VSX Gateway',
    'Name:            chckpt-fw1a',
    'Security Policy: VS-policy',
    'Installed at:    12Jan2023 21:57:15',
    'SIC Status:      Trust',
    'Connections number: 52',
    'Connections peak: 152',
    'Connections limit:  14900',
]
```

Comment: it will do, you're storing them all inside a dictionary where the keys must be unique and you'd end up with multiple `VSID`s for example, perhaps you'd be better just creating a list of tuples but not sure what the json creation is about

Comment: You should probably be creating a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. Every time the VSID changes, you should start a new dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary, so you need to create a list of dictionaries, one for each VSID.

```
output_dicts = []

for  item in show_vs:
    splitted = item.split(": ")
    if len(splitted) <= 1:
        continue
    key, value = map(str.strip, splitted[:2])
    if key == 'VSID':
        new_dict = {}
        output_dicts.append(new_dict)
    new_dict[key] = value

jsn = json.dumps(output_dicts, indent=4)
print(jsn)
```

Comment: thank you @barmar, what if my first key in next set of 10 keys is not VSID and starts with X?

Comment: If there are other conditions that should start a new dictionary, add them to the `if` statement. E.g. `if key == 'VSID' or key.startswith('X'):`